# How to disable Multisite sign-up page?

Tags: multisite, redirect

If we try to access a non-existant Multisite site, e.g., `http://site1.example.com` or `http://example.com/site1/`, we are redirected to `http://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=site1`.

How to block this and redirect the browser to another page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### [Update]

An alternative (maybe better) is to use the following [constant](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Redirect_Nonexistent_Blogs) in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://example.com' );
```

---

At the very beginning of [`wp-signup.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-signup.php) file there is this code:

```
function do_signup_header() {
    do_action( 'signup_header' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'do_signup_header' );
```

So, it's just a matter of adding the `signup_header` action hook to break any further execution and redirect the browser to other URL.

Here, wrapped as a [Must Use Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins):

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Multisite - Prevent Sign-up Page
    Plugin Url: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/85529/12615
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
*/

add_action( 'signup_header', 'rbz_prevent_multisite_signup' );

function rbz_prevent_multisite_signup() 
{
    wp_redirect( site_url() );
    die();
}
```

Comment: @kaiser, always disliked this behavior in closed networks ;)

Comment: hey, unser @kaiser, there's a better alternative, IMO. Updated the A with it. Also published a [related one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/98151/12615).

Comment: I just wanted to state that I _dislike the core behavior_. In the meanwhile I found the regarding DropIns, when [I talked about them](http://franz-josef-kaiser.github.io/wpm_vie_presentation/). +1 on both answers.

Comment: Was messing around a lot with function to prevent redirects and .htaccess to recognize */wp-signup.php to redirect to the network home page. The `define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', %URL% );` finally solved it! +1 (noteworthy: result not necessarily visible on localhost with custom URL redirect using Windows hosts file)

Comment: Just tried running this as a MU plugin and is causing an error (headers already sent).

Comment: This is incorrect - the hook used should be `before_signup_header`, not `signup_header`. otherwise you receive 'Headers already sent' errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in [this article](http://www.kmbytes.com/blog/2014/11/29/wordpress-multisite-wp-signup-phpnew-redirect-fix/)

I had the wrong `SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL` setting value in my config file.

Comment: A link-only answer will become invalid with a dead link. Would you please [edit] and elaborate your answer in brief and then provide the link for additional information?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following to `wp-content/mu-plugins/disable-signups.php`:

```php
<?php
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'do_signup_header' );
```

The signup page will now say:

> Registration has been disabled.