# Customizing Deleted/Archived blogs warning pages

Tags: multisite

When we try to access a *Deleted* or *Archived* site in Multisite, WordPress shows a `wp_die()` message.

[image: This site has been archived or suspended.]

And this message appears for *Deleted* sites:

> This user has elected to delete their account and the content is no longer available.

How can we customize that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that deals with this is [**`ms_site_check()`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/ms-load.php#L71).

If existent, it will use the following files. And they should render a full custom HTML page.

- `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/blog-deleted.php'`
- `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/blog-inactive.php'`
- `WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/blog-suspended.php'`

Another option is to short-circuit the process and redirect the visitor. It has to be done with a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and here using a PHP 5.3 anonymous function as callback.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Prevent Archived/Deleted blogs warning in Multisite
 * Plugin Url: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/98151/1261
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
 * Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 */

add_filter( 
    'ms_site_check',
    function() 
    {
        // Super admins should be able to see it
        if( current_user_can( 'manage_network' ) )
            return;

        $blog = get_blog_details();
        if(
            '1' == $blog->deleted 
            or '2' == $blog->deleted
            or '1' == $blog->archived 
            or '1' == $blog->spam
        )
        {
            wp_redirect( network_site_url() );
            die();
        }
    } 
);
```

**Related Q&A:** [How to disable Multisite sign-up page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85530/12615)