# Redirect subdomain in Multisite installation?

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, subdomains

One of my clients has a Wordpress site that is a multisite installation. They are running a new campaign that I have set up as a page under the main site at `example.com/summer/`. However, they sent marketing materials to print that list the URL as `summer.example.com`. Is there any way to redirect that subdomain to the proper page without having to set up a whole new multisite?

I tried sending the `A` record of the subdomain to the IP address of the site. Then used `.htaccess` and added the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^summer\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/summer/$1 [R=301]
```

That redirects the subdomain to `example.com/wp-signup.php?new=summer`

Any ideas?

**Update:**
I've added the `wp-config` definition of `('NOBLOGREDIRECT', '%siteurl%')` which gets `summer.example.com` redirecting to `example.com`. This is not the fix I need, but just reporting back on potential fixes I'm seeing around.

Comment: I'd probably set up a new VirtualHost in Apache for summer.domain.com and put the rewrite rule there. At the moment it looks like the rewrite isn't happening and WordPress is trying to treat this as a new multisite.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130076/multisite-redirect-to-appropriate-domain-if-subdomain-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/summer/$1 [R=301]
> ```

You need to include the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive, ie. `[R=301,L]` and ensure this rule is near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the existing WordPress directives.

Without the `L` flag, processing continues and the request is further rewritten (by the WordPress front-controller) before the eventual (incorrect) redirect.